# When Scrolling Listview the deselected images also shown

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the problem that when i scrolling down the listview the hidden images shown...how this problem solved...?? Thanks in advance...
[image]
and this is my code:- 
    @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {

```
            View v = convertView;

            if(v==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v=li.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);

            }

            TextView Title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
            final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main);
            final ImageView img1 =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust_img);

final BinForAll listitem = mList.get(position);


            Title.setText(listitem.getTxt());

            //Desc.setText(listitem.getDesc());
            content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    if(img1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE && count>=0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        m1.remove(mList.get(position).getTxt());
                        Log.d("remove", mList.get(position).getTxt());
                    }
                    else if(img1.getVisibility()==View.GONE && count>0)
                    {
                        count--;
                        img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        m1.add(mList.get(position).getTxt());
                        Log.d("add", mList.get(position).getTxt());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not add more than 10 values..", 1).show();
                    }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView always reuses views. So you should check that the view is in appropriate state each time you prepare the view for the ListView via `Adapter.getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.

In order to solve your problem you can persist visibility state in your `final BinForAll listitem = mList.get(position);` object (just add boolean feald to the BinForAll class) and rewrite your getView method as following:

```
@Override 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if(v==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v=li.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);

        }

        TextView Title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main);
        final ImageView img1 =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust_img);

        final BinForAll listitem = mList.get(position);


        Title.setText(listitem.getTxt());
        // each time set visibility for your image view
        img1.setVisibility(listitem.isVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        //Desc.setText(listitem.getDesc());
        content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                if(img1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE && count>=0)
                {
                    count++;
                    img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // save visibility state
                    listitem.setVisible(false);
                    m1.remove(mList.get(position).getTxt());
                    Log.d("remove", mList.get(position).getTxt());
                }
                else if(img1.getVisibility()==View.GONE && count>0)
                {
                    count--;
                    img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // save visibility state
                    listitem.setVisible(true);
                    m1.add(mList.get(position).getTxt());
                    Log.d("add", mList.get(position).getTxt());
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not add more than 10 values..", 1).show();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: this is right but when scrolling listview the visible(Selected) images also hidden...

Comment: as I have wrote 'img1.setVisibility(listitem.isVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);' should avoid your problem.

Comment: suppose i have selected 2 rows and after i am scrolling down ...then after going back by scrolling up in listview those selected two rows also deselected...

Comment: Why? when you selected the 1st item - the onClick() method called, so you marked your BinForAll instance as "selected" by listitem.setVisible(true). After scrolling down and up your getView() called again for the 1st position and you can define that list item is selected by calling listitem.isVisible() and set visibility for your image view.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attributes to your listView

```
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me. however this one worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6682552/846316